# DAX query: trying to count unique entries that match two different criteria

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data table I've imported into PowerBI from an csv that is a large list of exam results. Each row represents the details of when that particular exam was taken by a particular student. Some students will have taken the same exam more than once resulting in multiple rows for the same student/subject.

| SUBJECT | STUDENT | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| English | Fred | Feb |
| Maths | Stuart | May |
| Science | Fred | Feb |
| Maths | Simon | Mar |
| Science | Peter | June |
| English | Peter | June |
| English | Fred | Oct |
| Maths | Paul | June |
| Maths | Fred | Jan |
| English | Stuart | June |

I'm trying to find a query that will return a count of the unique number of students that have taken a particular combination of subjects. So, for the example above, how many students have taken both English **and **Maths?

The correct return would be **2** as only fred and stuart have taken both subjects.

I'm very new to DAX and have tried nesting a range of different statements but just can't figure this out? Nothing seems to get even close to the result needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your combination is static, you can use the following measure :

```
Students English Maths Count = 
VAR EnglishStudents = 
    CALCULATETABLE (
        DISTINCT ( TableTest[STUDENT] ),
       TableTest[SUBJECT] = "English"
    )
VAR MathsStudents = 
    CALCULATETABLE (
        DISTINCT ( TableTest[STUDENT] ),
        TableTest[SUBJECT] = "Maths"
    )
VAR StudentsBoth = 
    INTERSECT ( EnglishStudents, MathsStudents )

RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( StudentsBoth )
```

[image]

If you need something dynamic, I would go for creating two slicers to select
Subject A and Subject B :

Create two seperate tables with the unique values of subjects :

```
UniqueSubjectsA = DISTINCT(TableTest[SUBJECT])

UniqueSubjectsB = DISTINCT(TableTest[SUBJECT])
```

Your model is like below :

[image]

Your dynamic measure :

```
Dynamic Students Count = 
VAR Subject1Selection = SELECTEDVALUE(UniqueSubjectsA[Subject])
VAR Subject2Selection = SELECTEDVALUE(UniqueSubjectsB[Subject])
VAR StudentsSubject1 = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        DISTINCT('TableTest'[STUDENT]),
        'TableTest'[SUBJECT] = Subject1Selection
    )
VAR StudentsSubject2 = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        DISTINCT('TableTest'[STUDENT]),
        'TableTest'[SUBJECT] = Subject2Selection
    )
VAR IntersectionStudents = INTERSECT(StudentsSubject1, StudentsSubject2)

RETURN COUNTROWS(IntersectionStudents)
```

[image]